# Can i shuffle 2 Array lists that match with what i want?

Tags: java

So, I am working on a school project, which consits on making a quiz app with randomized questions and answers, i was wondering if i could make 2 Array lists (one with the questions and one with the fake answers or distractors) and randomize them in a way that the shuffled questions goes with their respective distractors, so say for example i have 2 questions and 2 sets of distractors ready:

Questions

1. What color is the sky?
2. What pulls us to the ground when we jump?

Distractors

1. a) Yellow
   b) Purple
   c) Black
2. a) Magic
   b) Reptilian politicians
   c) The weight of our sins and failures

If i shuffle both of them then the question will display the wrong set of distractors, so is there a way i can match up the questions with their correct set of distractors? also, is there a way i can use a radio group for the distractors?

Comment: Carry related questions, answers and distractor answers in one object; this way you only have one array, and related stuff can never get mixed up with unrelated stuff.

Comment: IMO the tag _android-studio_ ins't related to this question.

Comment: Oh that's the program i'm using for this, thought it would be relevant or something, i'm kind of new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a map of Questions and list of Distractors. Then use Random number to print each question and there corresponding Distractors.

```
Map<Question, List<Distractor>> questionDistractorMap = getMap();
List<Question> ques = new ArrayList<>(questionDistractorMap.keySet());
Random random = new Random();
while(ques.size() > -1){
  int index = random.nextInt(ques.size());
  System.out.println("Question: " + ques.get(index));
  System.out.println("Distractors:" + questionDistractorMap.get(ques.get(index)));
  ques.remove(index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, although i'd like to know if after that i could use a radio group for the distractors.

Comment: Yeah, in the while loop, instead of sysout you could set the radio group values.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ArrayList, You should use Map or HashMap. Example:-

```
Map<String,String> mapOfQueAndDis=new HashMap<String,String>();
mapOfQueAndDis.put("question1","distractor1");
mapOfQueAndDis.put("question2","distractor2");
```

and so on...,

Put your Questions as key and Distractors as Value

Comment: I like that solution, although can i use a radio group for the distractors with map and hash map? Sorry for all the questions, it's just that i'm kind of new to programming and thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `Map<String, String>` you should consider using `Map<String, Set<String>>` as there are multiple distractors for a single question.